# C++ write filestream

Tags: c++, windows, stream, buffer, writer

I am writing an application that produces and logs a lot of data in the form of ASCII and binary output (not mixed, one or the other depending on the log).  The application is single-threaded (should make things easier) and I want to write my data to disk in the order that it was generated.  I need to implement a write(char* data) method that takes a null-terminated character array and writes it to disk.  Ideally, I want the function to buffer the data and return before the data is actually written to disk...I figure that there must be some way for Windows to setup a thread and do this in the background.  The only thing that I care about is that I get the data in the log file in the order that it was written.  What is the best way to do this?  Someone else implemented the current write method and it looks like:

```
    void writeData(const char* data, int size) 
    { 
        if (fp != 0)
            fwrite (data, 1, size, fp); 
    }
```

fp is the file pointer.

C++ Stdio.h header:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/

Comment: If it is only for Windows then you could use overlapped io to do it, however it can be complex to get working properly.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I ended up trying to use Boost::Thread library.  I'm still working on the solution, but I found this very helpful: http://boqian.weebly.com/c-programming.html

Answer (score 0):

In multi-thread, may be you can use something like log queue.
In single-thread, the order is guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking Windows-only then you pretty much have two options: [Overlapped I/O through the WinAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or setting up a separate thread in your program to handle file I/O (which can potentially be cross-platform by using pthreads)